# How can I append an array to google sheet columns using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

`var arr=["aaa","bbb","ccc"];`
I want to append it to columns
`B7:D7`
Using google script
to `set B7 as "aaa"
C7 as "bbb"
and D7 as "ccc"`

Comment: As a simple Google Apps Script for putting the values to the active sheet, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B7:D7").setValues([arr])` can be achieved your goal. But from your question, I cannot understand about your detail situation. So if this was not the direct solution, I apologize. When you provide the current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a row array.
You want to set value to a column.
use "transpose" to create a column array from row array
Then set value to the column

ref

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95178/transposing-column-to-row

A column of values is represented in Apps Script as [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]. A row is represented as [['a', 'b', 'c']]. The following functions transform one to the other:

```
function col2row(column) {
  return [column.map(function(row) {return row[0];})];
} 

function row2col(row) {
  return row[0].map(function(elem) {return [elem];});
}
```